# Checking if object contains X in jQuery / ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

How would I go about checking if a Object returned by a API contains X?

This is the closest I have gotten, without getting any errors:

```
$.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {

var email_response = {response};         

if (Object.values((JSON.stringify(email_response))).indexOf('"response"') > -1) {
            console.log('Is valid');
         
         else (console.log('Not valid'));
});
```

After running it results with the "Not valid" response from the `if else` function, even though the text "valid" is present in the return where "Is valid" would be the expected result.

Stringified using `console.log(JSON.stringify(email_response));` this is what is returned from the API:

```
{"response":{"address":"test@domain.com","status":"valid","sub_status":"role_based_catch_all","free_email":false,"did_you_mean":null,"account":"test","domain":"domain.com","domain_age_days":"10116","smtp_provider":"","mx_found":"true","mx_record":"mx.domain.com","firstname":null,"lastname":null,"gender":null,"country":null,"region":null,"city":null,"zipcode":null,"processed_at":"2022-03-12 12:41:38.306"}}
```

I have tried to not stringify it as well, but this has the same result as explained above.

The following does also not see the specified text as present:

```
    Object.keys(email_response).forEach(function(key) {
    if ((email_response)[key] == 'valid') {
        console.log('Is valid');}
        else (console.log('Not valid'));
    
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`valid` is not a key, it's a value.  You need to check for the key `status` like this.

```
$.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {

    if (response.hasOwnProperty('status') && response.status === 'valid') {
        console.log('Is valid');
         
    } else {
        console.log('Not valid');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you dont have to stringify if you want to get some data

```
$.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {

var status= response.status; // valid

//or 
console.log("status",response.status); // valid or undefined

 });
```

but if for some reasons you like to create a new object, use this code

```
var email_response = {"response":response}; 

var status= email_response.response.status; // valid
```